# How to to search a sentences and replace based on specific conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs

I mean for **pointer**: `_# _`, and for **pointed sentence**: `_# some dynamic words _`.

I want to find a `sentence`.

1. `if (sentence contained pointer)` then `remove` the `pointer`.

```
const stringVal = "being _#kind_, I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great";
const searchSentence = "a kind man";
```

**Hint:** `a kind man` contains `two pointer`, So I have to `remove` it, because both `pointers` exists in `searchSentence`, but other `pointers` will alive, because they are not in `searchSentence`.

**So result is:**

```
stringVal = "being _#kind_, I am a kind man, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great";
```

I tried something like below:

```
searchSentence.trim().split(/\b\s+/).forEach(item => {
    stringVal = stringVal.replace(`_#${item}_`, item);
});
```

my solution only remove the `first pointer` exists in `stringVal`.

**Note:** `stringVal` is dynamic and can be changed, so only the conditions should be considered and also the `searchSentence` maybe contains `one or more pointers`, so all them should be removed.

**Important**: the value of `searchSentence` variable, should be find its exact match in `stringVal` value, then if there exists any pointer within that, they should be removed.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Where are the 'pointers' determined?

Comment: @JoelHager Thank you for comment, pointers already exist within `stringVal` and also keep in mid `stringVal` is dynamic I mean can be different but with same conditions.

Comment: What I'm saying is, are the 'pointers' always `_#thepointer_`?

Comment: @JoelHager, yeah it always as `_#thepointer_`,  but keep in mind `thepointer` is some words for searching.

Comment: Please also have a look again as it is edited

Comment: So the 'pointer' is just a word/letter that you're specifying in a sample set? So there are no special characters/etc?

Comment: I am really sorry for my `English`, as I cant understand you, I am only trying to remove `_# _` from `stringVal` only exists in position of `searchSentence`

Comment: two `last pointer` still exists because they are out of `a kind man` and I am not searching them

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please kindly have a look if it can be done with `regex`

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the application of regex if you explicitly *know* the words you're trying to remove...

Comment: Use this: `searchSentence.trim().split(/\b\s+/).forEach(element => stringVal = stringVal.replace(new RegExp(`_#${element}_`, 'g'), element));`. You just need to use global flag

Comment: @Mandy8055, this removes all `matched pointers`, I want to remove only those appears in `search`

Comment: To remove only that you can use positive lookahead in the regex. Something like `_#${element}_(?=man)`. Notice you can provide **man** dynamically.

Comment: @Mandy8055 thank you, `searchSentence` and `stringVal`, I mentioned in `Note`, they are not always same, they can different I just shown an example

Comment: You can try [**this**](https://repl.it/repls/ZestyToughFields) code for the moment. Please let me know if it helps. Then we can improve the code style and performance

Comment: @Mandy8055 thank you for your efforts, this time it shows me `SyntaxError, Invalid regular expression invalid group specifier name`

Comment: Use the repl which I attached. It runs fine. See [here](https://repl.it/repls/ZestyToughFields).You can run it directly there.Run [sample](https://imgur.com/a/EiDnUxR?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the solution below. Notice both the occurrences of **kind sample man** changes.(and that is your requirement I presume)

```js
//var searchSentence = "a kind sample man";
//var stringVal = "I am a _#kind_ _#sample_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great. I am also a _#kind_ _#sample_ _#man_.";
 var searchSentence = "kind people is";
 var stringVal = "being _#kind_, I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great";
searchSentence.trim().split(/\b\s+/).forEach((item, index) => {
    let splitSearch = searchSentence.split(" ")[index + 1];
    stringVal = stringVal.replace(new RegExp(`_?#?${item}_? (?=_?#?${splitSearch}_?)`,'g'), item + " ")
stringVal = stringVal.replace(new RegExp(`(?<=${item} )_?#?${splitSearch}_?`, 'g'), splitSearch);
});
console.log(stringVal)
```

Comment: Thank you bro, your solutions work only in some cases. example

`var stringVal = "being _#kind_, I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great";`

now if search new words example: `var searchSentence = "kind people"`;

this time does not work, as you can see I searched `kind people`, so at the end there is two `kind people` which both have `pointers` so both of them their pointer should be removed.

Comment: Updated the regular Expression as per you requirement @Muhammad. I thought that every word in the `searchSentence` contains the pointer. The fix was easy. Apply `?` quantifier 0 or 1 on the pointers. Just a small suggestion; You should always create your test cases on any [online regex compiler](https://regex101.com/). So it will be easy for the answering person to try the edge cases  and create a regex that suits your requirements. It helps both the Op and the anwer giver.

Comment: Thank you bro, I used your updated, and I searched `kind people is` from `I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great`. the result is: `I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love kind people, kind people is very great`. Here as you can `kind people is` exists at the end but your solutions removed `pointers` from middle `... love kind people, ..` also which is not expected.

Comment: Please give all of the edge cases which you think might succeed and fail

Comment: please see my `question` the `Important`, until you know what exactly the answer is

Comment: **Important**: the value of `searchSentence` variable, should be find its exact match in `stringVal` value, then if there exists any pointer within that, they should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one, I think it should do it.

```js
var searchSentence = "kind people is"
var stringVal = "I am a _#kind_ _#man_, I love _#kind_ people, _#kind_ people is very great"
var indeces = []
var stringArray = stringVal.replace(/,/g, ' ,')
 .replace(/_#[a-z]*_/ig, m => m.substr(2, m.length - 3))
 .split(' ')
 .forEach((item, index, all) => { 
    var found = true
    var tmpIndeces = []
    searchSentence.split(' ').forEach((searchItem, index2) => {
      found = found && all[index + index2] === searchItem
      tmpIndeces.push(index + index2)
    })
    if (found) indeces = [...indeces, ...tmpIndeces]
  })

var result = stringVal.replace(/,/g, ' ,').split(' ').map((item, index) => 
  indeces.includes(index) ? item.replace(new RegExp(searchSentence.trim().split(/\b\s+/).map(s => `_#${s}_`).join('|'), 'g'), m => m.substr(2, m.length - 3)) : item)
  .join(' ').replace(/ ,/g, ',')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, and now when there is a comma, Example: `searchSentence = "people, kind people"` or `searchSentence  = "kind people, kind"` does not work.

Comment: and also if `searchSentence = "kind m"` does not work, but `kind man` is ok or `kind peo`  does not work but `kind people` is ok

Comment: because some time half of a word can be selected too.

Comment: According to me this is one of the best answer which pass all the edge cases. Its one of the worthy solutions. Isn't it? +1 for this asnwer

Comment: Thank you bro, Yeah it very near, please if you have time only correct the `,` and also `kind m` or `kind peo`, or `kind ma` something like that

Comment: Only and only does not work with `,` and with a `complete word + one, or two, three or n letter of next word`

Comment: @Muhammad.This is working for kind peo, etc.According to you **kind peo** should discard any changes. Check it [**here**](https://repl.it/repls/ZestyToughFields). Also the `,` part is not working because in the code it is splitting based on space. i.e. `.split(" ")`. To check it uncomment the code in the repl I attached above.